# Reset entire series data and redraw in highcharts

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts, html-select, stacked-chart

I am currently working on an angular 5 application adn using highcharts for charts. I have a stacked bar chart with me. It plots the volume of positive, neutral, negative data across various categories.
The xAxis categories are

```
['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3', 'Cat4', 'Cat5']
```

and stacking normal

```
 plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
  }
```

and the series data is in the format

```
series : [
      {name : 'positive', data : [1,5,6,8,9]},
      {name : 'neutral', data : [2,6,7,8,3]},
      {name : 'negative', data : [3,6,4,2,8]}
    ]
```

It works great. Now, I have an array called categorySentimentData, where each object contains a company value as well as seriesData value (which is in the required format to be fed to our chart).

```
    {company : company.companyname,
    seriesData : [
      {name : 'positive', data : positiveArray},
      {name : 'neutral', data : neutralArray},
      {name : 'negative', data : negativeArray}
    ]
```

Now I have a select tag whose options are various company names. When i select a different company, the chart should be fed with the appropriate series data and redrawn.
My chart creation code :

```
this.categorySentimentChart = new Highcharts.Chart('compChart',{
  chart : {
    type : 'bar'
  },
  title : {
    text : this.selectedCompany
  },
  xAxis : {                
    categories : categoryList,        
  },
  yAxis : {                
    title : {
      text : ''
    }
  },
  legend : {
    reversed : true, 
    layout : 'horizontal',
    align : 'center',
    verticalAlign : 'bottom'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series : this.categorySentimentData.filter((com) => com.company == this.selectedCompany)[0].seriesData
});
```

I have searched for ways to change series data and redraw the chart. They all have the same code

```
chart.series[0].setData([1,2,3,4,5]);
```

Is there a way i can reset the entire series data and redraw it? This is function i currently use when a company is selected

```
 onCompanyChange() {    
let targetSeriesData = this.categorySentimentData.filter((com) => com.company == this.selectedCompany)[0].seriesData;    
this.categorySentimentChart.series.forEach((item, index) => {      
  this.categorySentimentCompetitorChart.series[index].setData(targetSeriesData[index], false);
});
console.log(this.categorySentimentCompetitorChart.series);
this.categorySentimentCompetitorChart.redraw();  }
```

But this isn't working. The chart disappears as soon as I click a company. Please guide me on how to achieve the desired functionality. Here is a jsfiddle link recreating the scenario as close as possible https://jsfiddle.net/j8zyx6ba/19/ . TIA

Comment: You do not have redraw chart after setData - the chart should be redrawn by default. The thing to be remembered is - do not reuse your data for updates. You should always use a fresh copy of the data in setData because Highcharts internally modifies it. If you still have a problem - create a live example with your issue, e.g. on jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j8zyx6ba/19/ I've recreated the scenario. As soon as a new company is selected in the select drop down, the chart should be loaded with that company's data and redrawn. TIA

Comment: Fixed jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ss5vufoo/

Comment: It's working, Thank you.